# UI control for optimal mobile and desktop experience

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, zurb-foundation, modernizr

I have been looking for a simple way to optimize a responsive website with dynamic content, for both mobile and desktop users.

I have quite a bit of styling & js functionality that only makes sense on a desktop environment, rather than a mobile one, and vice versa. On the other hand my layout only breaks down below average tablet size, which makes it hard to point out where to make the switch.

I would like to avoid bombarding both mobile/desktop users with everything, instead switching the stylesheets and scripts that need to be loaded. Since the site remains constant and loads in the essential content with ajax, I would prefer to keep all other load times to a bare minimum.

My initial thought was to write a modernizr function to load in a different css and js file according to the detection of a touch feature. But that was before I found out many non-mobile browsers now see themselves as touch enabled :/

I'm wondering how some of you work around this for now, without having to stick to a device-width media query, going for one of both or having to worry that some browser versions or devices won't be covered.

Comment: The best way *is* to use `device-width` media queries. They're the most reliable, even in JavaScript, it's the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) is a grate tool for that. Is very siple, i use de jQuery vesion like this:

```
if( jQuery.browser.mobile ){ //code }
```